# c# Google Api Calendar Oauth 2.0

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I need help.
I need to create an app, which takes all events from different calendars from my company, and display them in computers in conferences rooms. This is created, works good. To authenticate I use Oauth 2.0 like google wants, but I tested it only on my computer. When the app was launched on the computer in the conference room, the app needed logging into google account, which surprised me, because I put my oauth 2.0 credentials into my code, so I thought that this would be enough.
How can I skip that part, to authenticate only from code level and not display Oauth popup message to user?

Comment: You mean you are not able to access the Google API without logging into the Google? you don't need to login to Google if you are calling API from your computer? can you share the relevant code please?

Comment: @Chetan calls to a google api that access private user data must be authorized.  This is what the author is referring to not logging into google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your code locally you are authorizing it.  If you are using the official Google api .net client library then it is storing your authorization credentials in the %appdata% folder on your machine.   Once you move this to the computers in the conference rooms they have not been authorized and there for will require that you authorize them.   So you should be able to just run it once on each machine and authorize it and it will be all set.

If you do however have a google workspace account, I would recommend you look into using a service account and configuring domain wide delegation this would stream line your process a bit.

The following example shows how to use a service account with domain wide deligation.

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
.CreateWithUser("user@yourdomain.com")  // delegate to user on workspace.
.CreateScoped(new[] {CalendarService.ScopeConstants.Calendar});
```

Comment: So do you mean that create Service Account, and after that add this account to specific calendar, and authorize using this account key?

Comment: If you have a google workspace account, Your workspace admin can set up delegation to the service account which will give it access to all of the calendars on your domain.   Service accounts only work with google calendar in combination with Google workspace.

Comment: Bro this solution with copying TokenResponse from %appdata% work very good, as i expected. But one thing, is there posibility when app will need this token again. Or maybe when this token expire?

Comment: Go to your project on Google developer console -> the Oauth2 consent screen -> Look for "Publishing status" make sure its set to production.   Once set to production your refresh token will not expire.   You should be good to go.

Comment: After you have set it to production make sure you request a new refresh token.

Comment: Finally i decided to create Service Account and assing it to every calendar. 
What was weird, that returning all calendars for that account returned null, so i found solution where firstly you need to Insert every added calendarId from 'API' side, and after that action, returning list of avaiable calendars do not return null.

Comment: Make sure you specified the user who you want to delegate in your code. Check my edit.

Comment: I did as in the example from you, which is strange, in any browser I can join the meeting without any problem. However, sometimes in Google Chrome, in guest mode, information pops up that you can't join the meeting for security reasons, where at the same time in incognito mode you can...

Comment: I haven't granted domain-wide delegation to the service account, could this be a problem?

Comment: Yes google calendar only works with service accounts if you have continued domain wide delegation though your google workspace domain.